# Ayuda con trigger al borrar e insertar

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, trigger, sql-server-2012

Tengo estás tablas y este **trigger**

```
CREATE TABLE Productos
(
id_Cod INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
cod_prod VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
nombre VARCHAR(50)NOT NULL,
existencia INT NOT NULL,
)
GO

CREATE TABLE Historial
(fecha DATE,
cod_prod VARCHAR(4),
descripcion VARCHAR(100), 
usuario VARCHAR(30))
GO

CREATE TRIGGER trProductoEliminado
ON Productos FOR DELETE
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @cod_prod VARCHAR(4)
SELECT @cod_prod = cod_prod FROM Deleted  
INSERT INTO Historial VALUES(getdate(), @cod_prod, 'registro eliminado', system_user)
GO
```

Al momento de borrar registros uno por uno mediante un `where`, si se inserta el registro en la tabla historial; pero al momento de borrar todos los registros sin el `where` en la tabla historial solo se inserta 1 registro. ¿Como le hago para que se insertan todos los borrados?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar un insert select

```
CREATE TRIGGER trProductoEliminado
  ON Productos
  FOR DELETE
  AS
  SET NOCOUNT ON
INSERT INTO Historial
SELECT getdate(),
       cod_prod,
       'registro eliminado',
       system_user
FROM Deleted

GO
```

Comment: Lo checaré, gracias